# controller not accepting model values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

learning MVC4/C#. just simply trying to post a list of movies back to the controller but it's null. Am I defining the classes properly?

I have the following model

```
 namespace videostore.Models
 {

     public class MovieSummary
     {
         public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
     }

     public class Movie
     {
         public string name { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

following controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveMovies(MovieSummary movieList)
    {

    }
```

and the following html

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
           e.preventDefault();
           $.post('/SaveMovies', $('form').serialize(), function (data) {
           });
        });
     });
 </script>

 <form>
      <input type="hidden" name="movie" value="Man of Steel" />
      <input type="hidden" name="movie" value="The Dark Knight" />
      <input type="hidden" name="movie" value="Iron Man" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you try for all textboxes name as array like name="movie[]"

Comment: Would u please show the codes of Get method.

Comment: there is no get method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.. I hope it will work

```
<form>
      <input type="hidden" name="movieList[0].name" value="Man of Steel" />
      <input type="hidden" name="movieList[1].name" value="The Dark Knight" />
      <input type="hidden" name="movieList[2].name" value="Iron Man" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

See more details at [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The controller is not accepting the values could be because your property name and control name is different. Try changing your Movie class and form like this

```
 public class Movie
 {
     public string movieName { get; set; }
 }


 <form>
      <input type="hidden" name="movieName" value="Man of Steel" />
      <input type="hidden" name="movieName" value="The Dark Knight" />
      <input type="hidden" name="movieName" value="Iron Man" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>
```

Comment: that works, but the controller only accepts the first value, I need to be able to collect all within a model as a list